# CSS. Transition. Как сделадь два transition

Tags: javascript, css3, transition

CSS. Transition. Как сделадь два transition, чтобы сначало выполнялось одно свойство transition, потом через секунду второе я попробовал, но получилось коряво. Если можно с помощью JS, то предлагайте.

```css
#house{
 height:90%;
 width:90%;
 
}
#menu{
 
 width:6%;
 height:6%;
 background-color:#CCCCCC;
 cursor:pointer;
}
#menu_main{
 position:fixed;
 top:1%;
 left:1%;
}

#gee{
 
 position:fixed;
 top:-1%;
 width:0%;
 height:0%;
  transition:width 1s ease;
  transition:height 1s ease 1s;
 overflow:hidden;
 left:2%;
 color:white;
 margin-bottom:3%;
 
}
#om ul li{
 font-size:195%;
 background-color:#CCCCCC;
 list-style-image:none;
 margin-top:2px;
 list-style-type:none;
    margin-left:-2%;
 text-align:center;

}
#menu:hover .tooltip{

 height:100%;
  width:100%;

}
```

```html
<di<div id = "menu_main">
<div id  = "menu">
<center>
<img src = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/04/03/00/41/house-309113_960_720.png" id = "house"></img>
</center>
<div id = "om">
<ul class = "tooltip" id = "gee">
<li>Главная Страница</li>
<li>Карта Сайта</li>
<li>Контакты</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У `transition` есть подробная запись, как у `background`.

Есть:

- `transition-property`
- `transition-duration`
- `transition-delay`
- `transition-timing-function`

С помощью них можно настроить `transition` для разных свойств.

Посмотрите пример.

```css
#house {
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
}

#menu {
  width: 6%;
  height: 6%;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#menu_main {
  position: fixed;
  top: 1%;
  left: 1%;
}

#gee {
  position: fixed;
  top: -1%;
  width: 0%;
  height: 2%;
  transition-property: width, height;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-delay: 1s,0s;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 2%;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}

#om ul li {
  font-size: 195%;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  list-style-image: none;
  margin-top: 2px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: -2%;
  text-align: center;
}

#menu:hover .tooltip {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition-delay: 0s, 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu_main">
  <div id="menu">
    <center>
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/04/03/00/41/house-309113_960_720.png" id="house" />
    </center>
    <div id="om">
      <ul class="tooltip" id="gee">
        <li>Главная Страница</li>
        <li>Карта Сайта</li>
        <li>Контакты</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```